# Hiding Shipping Method for current Logged in/Guest user if a condition method

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping-methods, checkoutsession

I'm using Magento 2.1. Currently, I'm having two shipping methods. One is UPS and another is Flatrate. If my product's attribute returns true, I want to hide Flatrate shipping method from frontend only, for Logged in/Guest User and if the product's attribute returns false I have to hide the UPS shipping method. How can I write the code for the same in my custom module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that the attribute code is called `attribute_code` so the getter name is `getAttributeCode()`.

You need to create an `arround` plugin on the flatrate carrier model and UPS carrier model where you can check your conditions and return or not the shipping rate result.

You need to create a module and add this in the `di.xml` file

```
<type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate">
    <plugin name="[module]-flatrate" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Flatrate" />
</type>

<type name="Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier">
    <plugin name="[module]-ups" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Ups" />
</type>
```

Then create the file `[Vendor]/[Module]/Plugin/Flatrate.php`

```
<?php 

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin;

class Flatrate
{
    public function arroundCollectRates(
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
    ) {
        $items = $request->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->getAttributeCode()) {
                 //if your attribute value is true don't show this method
                 return false;
            }
        }
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

and this plugin class that handles UPS shipping method `[Vendor]/[Module]/Plugin/Ups.php`

```
<?php 

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin;

class Ups
{
    public function arroundCollectRates(
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Ups $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
    ) {
        $items = $request->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->getAttributeCode()) {
                 //if one attribute value is true show the method
                 return $proceed();
            }
        }
        //if all the products had the value false don't show UPS.
        return false;
    }
}
```

But keep in mind  that I didn't test the code so watch out for typos.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have to create Tablerate.php or Flatrate.php

Comment: Flatrate.php. Sorry. I got carried away a bit.

Comment: For the second point u have mentioned here, If any of the products has the attribute value True I wish to hide the Flatrate shipping method always and display the UPS method.

Comment: @sree. I edited the code. Again, watch out for typos.

Comment: can u please check that $subject in Ups.php

Comment: you are right. it should be `Ups`. As a general thing, when working with plugins, the first parameter of a plugin is the original object you are using. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: Both of the shipping methods disappeared now and now "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time" are displaying

Comment: At least something happens. It means the code does something. You can try to debug step by step with different products in your cart to see what I did wrong.

Comment: Even after resolving the errors the shipping methods are not hiding.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no other idea. I thought it would work.