# 500 internal server error on plugin creation - Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods, ups

I'm using Magento 2.1 I'm trying to hide the shipping method based on product attribute. I followed the solution found here [Hiding Shipping Method for current Logged in/Guest user if a condition method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161059/hiding-shipping-method-for-current-logged-in-guest-user-if-a-condition-method)

But as in the comment provided both the shipping methods are disappearing and "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time" are displaying under shipping Methods.

I found the following error in console

> {"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate::collectRates() must be an instance of Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest,none given in /home/my_server/public_html/vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php:64\

My Plugin file Flatrate.php is as follows

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\Module\Plugin;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateCollectorInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

class Flatrate
{
    public function aroundCollectRates(
    \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
    ) {
        $items = $request->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->getAttributeCode()=='ups') {
                 //if your attribute value is true don't show this method
                 return false;
            }
        }
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use plugin with around method and if the function have arguments you need to pass it in $proceed Callback method.

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\Module\Plugin;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateCollectorInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

class Flatrate
{
    public function aroundCollectRates(
    \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
    ) {
        $items = $request->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->getAttributeCode()=='ups') {
                 //if your attribute value is true don't show this method
                 return false;
            }
        }
        return $proceed($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... The 500 internal server error got resolved. But still, my Flatrate shipping method is not getting hidden.  Did you have any idea about that?

Comment: It is depend on what condition you want to hide. Please explain it so i can reply on it.

Comment: Here I'm trying to check the attribute code of the products in the cart here 

`if ($item->getProduct()->getAttributeCode()=='ups')`

if any of the products in the cart having "ups" product attribute it should hide the flatrate shipping method. otherwise display flatrate only

Comment: first of all check $item->getProduct()->getAttributeCode() what value it returns

Comment: Yes.. I checked that. Its returning null.. Sorry I'm new to magento

Comment: No need to sorry.. Yes so you are checking on wrong so first tell me which attribute you have created for shiping carrier?

Comment: attribute code is 'ups'. if the product is having this attribute == 'yes' Then the shipping method 'flatrate' should be hidden. otherwise 'ups' shipping method should display. If more than one product is present in cart then it should display ups shipping method

Comment: $items = $request->getAllItems();
         $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $customProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
            if ($customProduct->getData('ups')) {
                //if your attribute value is true don't show this method
                return false;
            }
        }

Comment: Please update your code to above here you need to replace $customProduct->getData('ups') ->  'ups' to your attribute code

Comment: Thanks Flatrate  shipping method got hidden when the product has attribute 'ups'. But at the same time. When I added a product which does not have the attribute 'ups', the flatrate is hidden and ups shipping method is not displaying.

Comment: The plugin code i wrote for this is

`class Ups
{
public function aroundCollectRates(\Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier $subject,\Closure $proceed,\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address RateRequest $request) {$items = $request->getAllItems();
$customProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
foreach ($items as $item) {if (!$customProduct->getData('ups')) {return false;}}return $proceed($request); }}`