# Magento 2 : Update Flatrate Price in Summary Block Based on Zip Code

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, shipping, shipping-methods

I want to overwrite summary block on cart page. I'm fetching dynamic values from an API, based on zip code user have provided. I need to

- fetch input value that user entered in zip code box
- passing this value to the API call
- getting result and displayed near shipping method name using ajax.

Here I'm trying to integrate dynamic value with flat rate shipping method. The possible problem that may appear is that dynamic value will be inserted into core_config_data table if a user tried to add any product to cart. When any other user gets into cart page, shipping method price that displayed will be same price that previous user had, which is fetched from DB (core_config_data). Any solution for this

1. To overwrite summary block
2. To resolve possible issue.

I followed [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161059/hiding-shipping-method-for-current-logged-in-guest-user-if-a-condition-method) method to overwrite flat rate shipping method.

Comment: Anyone who can help me here?

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate` class by creating a preference in your modules `etc/di.xml`:

```
<preference for="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate" type="Your\Model\Model\Carrier\Flatrate"/>
```

The class `Your\Model\Model\Carrier\Flatrate` would be a copy of `Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate` with an alteration made to the `getShippingPrice`, for example:

```
private function getShippingPrice(RateRequest $request, $freeBoxes)
{
    $shippingPrice = false;

    $configPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
    if ($this->getConfigData('type') === 'O') {
        // per order
        $shippingPrice = $this->itemPriceCalculator->getShippingPricePerOrder($request, $configPrice, $freeBoxes);
    } elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') === 'I') {
        // per item
        $shippingPrice = $this->itemPriceCalculator->getShippingPricePerItem($request, $configPrice, $freeBoxes);
    }

    // alter shipping price based on zip code
    if ($request->getDestPostcode() == 78747) {
        $shippingPrice += 10;
    }

    $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($shippingPrice);

    if ($shippingPrice !== false && (
            $request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $freeBoxes
        )
    ) {
        $shippingPrice = '0.00';
    }
    return $shippingPrice;
}
```

Comment: Is this working if i typed a zip code in the Zip/Postal Code Block and it will display the price amount fetched from api ? Similar working of ups/FedEx shipping?

Comment: Yes, it will update the price of the flat rate shipping method when you enter a zip code.

Comment: How can I fetch the shipping price value from a controller execute function here?