# How to create a shipping method in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm using the Magento website 2.2.5, I want to create new custom shipping method for my store, how can I create custom shipping method or any guide about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the document for Creating a shipping method in Magento 2 on the link : https://inchoo.net/magento-2/creating-a-shipping-method-in-magento-2/

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any question

Answer (score 3):

Create following files to add a custom shipping method.

I have taken a shipping method code as "**testshipping**".

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="carriers" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="320" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">

            <group id="testshipping" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Test Shipping</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Method Name</label>
                </field>
                <field id="price" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Price</label>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="handling_type" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="70" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Calculate Handling Fee</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Shipping\Model\Source\HandlingType</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="handling_fee" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Handling Fee</label>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="sort_order" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1000" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Sort Order</label>
                </field>
                <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </field>
                <field id="sallowspecific" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="900" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                    <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                    <source_model>Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="910" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                </field>
                <field id="showmethod" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="920" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Show Method if Not Applicable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="specificerrmsg" translate="label" type="textarea" sortOrder="800" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Displayed Error Message</label>
                </field>
            </group>

        </section>

    </system>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <testshipping>
                <active>1</active>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
                <model>Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier\Testshipping</model>
                <name>Testshipping</name>
                <price>00.00</price>
                <title>Test Shipping</title>
                <type>I</type>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is not available. To use this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
            </testshipping>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Carrier/Testshipping.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

class Testshipping extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'testshipping';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return ['testshipping' => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return bool|Result
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier('testshipping');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('testshipping');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        /*you can fetch shipping price from different sources over some APIs, we used price from config.xml - xml node price*/
        $amount = $this->getConfigData('price');

        $method->setPrice($amount);
        $method->setCost($amount);

        $result->append($method);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we hide specific shipping method option from the list with condition

Comment: @jafarpinjar Yes, you can. Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/161061/48571

Answer (score 0):

please refer below link of DevDocs

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout-add-custom-carrier.html